# How to use python to extract the mentions?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm working on a code using python to extract the mentions from a tweet text.

The parameter is a tweet text. This function should return a list containing all of the mentions in the tweet, in the order they appear in the tweet. Each mention in the returned list should have the initial mention symbol removed, and the list should contain every mention encountered — including repeats, if a user is mentioned more than once within a tweet.Here are two examples:

```
>>>extract_mentions('@AndreaTantaros- You are a true journalistic\
professional. I so agree with what you say. Keep up the great\
work!@RepJohnLewis ')
['AndreaTantaros','RepJohnLewis']
>>>extract_mentions('@CPAC For all the closet #libertarians attending \
#CPAC2016 , I'll be there Thurs/Fri -- speaking Thurs. a.m. on the main\
stage. Look me up! @CPAC')
['CPAC','CPAC']
```

a mention begins with the '@' symbol and contains all alphanumeric characters up to (but not including) a space character, punctuation, or the end of a tweet.

How can I extract the mentions from the string? And sorry, I haven't learned about regex, is there any other ways?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following regular expression as it disregards email addresses.

```
(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})
```

**Example Code**

```
import re

text = "@RayFranco is answering to @jjconti, this is a real '@username83' but this is an@email.com, and this is a @probablyfaketwitterusername";

result = re.findall("(^|[^@\w])@(\w{1,15})", text)

print(result);
```

This returns:

```
[('', 'RayFranco'), (' ', 'jjconti'), ("'", 'username83'), (' ', 'probablyfaketwi')]
```

Note that, twitter allows max 15 characters for twitter usernames. Based on [Twitter specs](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299#error):

> Your username cannot be longer than 15 characters. Your real name can
>   be longer (20 characters), but usernames are kept shorter for the sake
>   of ease. A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters
>   A-Z, numbers 0-9) with the exception of underscores, as noted above.
>   Check to make sure your desired username doesn't contain any symbols,
>   dashes, or spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Use `regex` :

```
import re
input_string = '@AndreaTantaros- You are a true journalistic professional. I so agree with what you say. Keep up the great work!@RepJohnLewis '
result = re.findall("@([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15})", input_string)
```

Output : `['AndreaTantaros', 'RepJohnLewis']`

If you want to remove email-addresses first, simply do :

```
re.sub("[\w]+@[\w]+\.[c][o][m]", "", input_string)
```

Comment: what if someones' email address is - something@anything.edu??

Comment: That depends, you can simply have a regex matching exactly three characters after a `.`, like this : `[\w]+@[\w]+\.[a-z]{3}`. It hasn't mentioned by the OP exactly what she wants. @WasiAhmad

Comment: What if my email address is `hello@example.ninja`? Or `hello@example.nl`? Or `hello.there@example.com`? Or `hello+there@example.com`?